# Code To Search within the internal web pages from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed an internal portal.It is Live now and working properly. But for phase 2 I want the search functionality which include to search from the portal only that is, if user types a specific text in the search tab and press enter then it should display all the content displaying that text or line from the portal itself.

My portal contain some pdf and doc files.

Comment: hope this link will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd571509.aspx

Comment: It will try the link which you have given and get back to you if I have some query.Thanks

Comment: The link which you have given is fine, but I need to search the contents without going to any site like search.live.com in this case.It should work and find the html pages inside the portal without internet connection also.Please help in this regard.